# Read by both char and line from text file

Tags: java, file-io

For a VERY basic RPG (Well, top-down walking around game at present,) I want to make a method that reads a "save" file and stores it in memory (Saving comes later.) I'd like this save file to be user-friendly by having a way to make certain lines of it not be read by the method, so that I can put instructions on modifying it and such. Currently, the plan is to have it not read lines with a % in front, but that can change if % causes a problem.

The save format itself I'd like to have in one compressed block - one or two alphanumeric characters denote the contents of a single "tile." I don't want to simply have 169 lines for every screen of area, I'd rather have them in a compressed block of 13*13 (again, to be user-friendly.)

Essentially, how can I both
a) Detect if a line starts with %
b) If so, skip to next line
c) If not, read two characters at a time copying to string array
d) Skip blank lines

I understand BASIC IO, but I haven't been able to find a way of reading both by character and by line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I would use a `BufferedReader` to read the file line by line into individual `String` objects, and inspect the contents.  You can check if a line starts with a comment character by using the cunningly named `String.startsWith("%")` method, and get at individual characters in the line using `String.charAt(index)`, or double characters using `String.substring(start, start+2)`.

Comment: Sorry, one more quick question that dosen't warrant it's own topic: Is there any way of doing it (in a reasonably easy manner) that does not require every single method that interacts with that data (i.e. every single method) to have a throws IOException clause?

Comment: There's no way of removing the possibility of an `IOException` being thrown.  You need to decide how and where you want to handle it.  *One* possible way might be to catch the exception an throw an unchecked `RuntimeException`.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the scanner class http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html it should be able to do most of the work.

Answer (score 0):

I would read line-by-line with a Scanner, parse the first couple characters, and proceed if you need to.  Example:

```
Scanner lineReader = new Scanner(new FileReader(filename));
Scanner parser;
while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
  parser = new Scanner(scanner.nextLine());
  if(parser.hasNext())){ //checks for blank line
    String firstWord = parser.next();
    if(/*Check for %*/)
      continue;
    else
      //parse as you will
  }
}
```

Comment: Though, if your character pairs aren't delimited, you may not want to use a second Scanner to parse each line.